# Centralized token for concurrent asynchronous network tasks

Tags: ios, swift, rest, networking, token

I have an application that is pulling API data for multiple tasks within itself.

The main API data request is to pull the appointments for a given provider or location in our health system.
To have the proper keys to match the provider ID or location ID to the actual name, I pull that data from the API as well to make sure they are up to date.

I have it working so the network call checks if the current API token is active, and if not, automatically refreshes it and re-calls the network data.  Once the token is confirmed to either be currently active OR to be refreshed properly, it returns true.

However, the 3 different network pulls are calling data asynchronously and one will update the API token while the other is attempting to do the same and then the API token gets updated repeatedly within the same sequence unnecessarily.

To fix this, I am attempting to switch to a localized token function which checks if the current token is active, and if not refreshes it.  It also checks if there is a token update already in progress, and if so stops the other functions from updating it as well.  It also re-calls the original function in order to wait for the updated token to appear.

The problem I'm running into is I seem to have created a loop that crashes my app before the new token can appear.  Essentially what I'm guessing I need to solve this is to wait for a response before re-calling the loop, but I'm unsure on the best way to do this.

Here is my token check/refresh code:

My model also has a var tokenUpdateInProgress = false so that the new function can alert when a new update begins.

```
func isTokenActiveAndRefreshIfNot(_ completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
    print("running tokenActive function")
    var returnBool = false
    print("tokenUpdateInProgressz: \(tokenUpdateInProgress)")

    if tokenUpdateInProgress == false {
        print("no other update in progress, start the check here")
        tokenUpdateInProgress = true
        let resourceListURL = "https://api.carecloud.com/v2/oauth2/token_info"
        var request = URLRequest(url:URL(string:resourceListURL)!)
        request.addValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        var json = JSON()

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request){ data, response, error in
            print("data pull called in isTokenActive")
            if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                print("status code: \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
                httpStatusCode = httpResponse.statusCode
            }
            if httpStatusCode == 200 {
                print("token is current, proceed")
                tokenUpdateInProgress = false
                returnBool = true
                json = try! JSON(data: data!)
                for (_, _) in json {
                    if let expiration = json["expires_in"].string {
                        if let double = Double(expiration) {
                            let dateTime = Date()
                            let newDateTime = dateTime.addingTimeInterval(double)
                            tokenExpiresDateTime = newDateTime
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if httpStatusCode == 403 || httpStatusCode == 401 { 
                let downloadGroup = DispatchGroup()
                print("token is expired, need to refresh it")
                tokenUpdate = false
                downloadGroup.enter()
                refreshToken({ (tokenRefreshed) in. //this function refreshes my token successfully
                    if tokenRefreshed == true {
                        //can do something here if token refresh works correctly
                        returnBool = true
                        tokenUpdateInProgress = false
                        downloadGroup.leave()
                        downloadGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
                            //                        completion(returnItem)
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
            completion(returnBool)
            }.resume()
    } else if tokenUpdateInProgress == true {
        print("token update in progress, re-run check and wait for result")
        isTokenActiveAndRefreshIfNot { (result) in  //this creates a loop if network not working or token refresh not working for any reason.  This loops too fast and leads to a crash.
            returnBool = result
        }
        completion(returnBool)
    }

}
```

The three functions all pulling this data are:
1:

```
func monthSchedule(resourceID: String, locationID: String, page: Int, _ completion: @escaping ([appt]) -> ()){
    isTokenActiveAndRefreshIfNot { (tokenUpdated) in
        print("token update within monthschedule: \(tokenUpdated)")
    }
... runs network pull/API interpretation from token once confirmed ok
}
```

2:

```
func pullLocationsList(_ completion: @escaping ([Int: String]) -> ()){
    isTokenActiveAndRefreshIfNot { (tokenReady) in
        print("token ready for pull location list: \(tokenReady)")
    }
    ... runs network pull/API interpretation from token once confirmed ok
    }
```

3:

```
func pullResourceList(_ completion: @escaping ([Int: String]) -> ()){
    isTokenActiveAndRefreshIfNot { (tokenReady) in
        print("token ready for pull resource list: \(tokenReady)")
    }
        ... runs network pull/API interpretation from token once confirmed ok
    }
```

Comment: More information: This seems to crash due to a memory allocation problem. I get Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffee066bfe8) right at:  if tokenUpdateInProgress == false

Comment: Update: I believe I fixed it but not 100% sure. I was calling the token refresh function within appDelegate upon app load to try and make sure the token was already updated before the app started loading data.  When the launch screen attempted to disappear, I think it was deallocating and crashing the app since the looped function was still running.  When I only run the active token check within the regular ViewController, the crash went away.

Comment: Update again: This sometimes work and sometimes still crashes, so the same issue is still present (although improved)